# Select sold and unsold products

Tags: mysql, sql, select, product

I'm trying to select all products names and how many has been sold in current date, but I'm having a problem since not all products are sold everyday. (When the product has not been sold it must return 0)

TABLE PRODUCTS

```
ID         NAME
1          APPLE
2          PINEAPPLE
3          COFFE
```

TABLE SALES

```
ID         DATE
1          2014-01-13
2          2014-01-13
```

TABLE PRODUCTS_AND_SALES

```
SALE_ID    PRODUCT_ID      AMOUNT
1          3               2
1          1               1
2          3               1
```

What I expect to receive:

```
PRODUCT        AMOUNT
APPLE          1
PINEAPPLE      0
COFFE          3
```

What I receive:

```
PRODUCT        AMOUNT
APPLE          1
COFFE          3
```

My query:

```
select product, sum(amount) from products
join products_and_sales using (product_id)
join sales using (sale_id)
where date(dt_sale) = curdate()
group by product_id;
```

Comment: can you show what you tried? so we can see what have you done wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  select name as PRODUCT  ,  ifnull(sum(AMOUNT),0) amount from products p
  left join PRODUCTS_AND_SALES ps
  on p.id = ps.PRODUCT_ID
  group by product
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0851/5)

EDIT:

if you wanna use specefic date then use this

```
 select name as PRODUCT ,if(date = '2014-01-13' ,ifnull(sum(AMOUNT),0), 0 ) amount 
 from  products p

 left join PRODUCTS_AND_SALES ps on p.id = ps.PRODUCT_ID
 left join SALES s on s.id = ps.SALE_ID
 group by product
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca7cc/1)

just replace this date `2014-01-13` by the date you want. (curdate()) or what ever

Comment: But I want only the products sold in a specific date. Try your query only for products sold yesterday (2014-01-12)

Answer (score 0):

Use OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

if you show the query you use we will correct it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT pr.NAME, IFNULL(SUM(prs.AMOUNT), 0)
FROM PRODUCTS pr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS_AND_SALES prs ON pr.id = prs.product_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SALES sl ON sl.id = prs.sales_id AND date(s1.dt_sale) = curdate()
GROUP BY pr.NAME
```

Comment: But i want only the products sold in a specific date. Try your query only for products sold yesterday (2014-01-12)

Comment: @lizard Add the filter to the join condition as shown in the modified answer.

Comment: Doesnt work as it should... It returned all the products sold since the first date. But it's the closest I get, thanks.